# Storing FB likes in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-like, facebook-rest-api

I'm working on picture contest site which have to allow user to vote with facebook like button. At the end of a round, a have to check all picture likes and store it in our database. Well, what's proper way of doing this? How can I use [links.getStats](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.getStats/) function for getting that data and storing it in the database?

Similar question is found here:
[How can I store the number of facebook Likes of a particular url in my own database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544370/how-can-i-store-the-number-of-facebook-likes-of-a-particular-url-in-my-own-databa)
but it isn't answearing my question because I have to get exact number of likes/votes in short period in time.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC but any other solution should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a js callback to record the like button clicks (probably via an ajax call back to your db).

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // do something with response.session
});
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ for more details.